# pam_pkcs11 - Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user

Tags: linux, pam, openldap, smartcard

Whenever I try to use PAM with a smart card via `pam_pkcs11.so` I get the following error:

```
DEBUG:cert_vfy.c:38: Couldn't verify Cert: Peer's ceritifacte issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error since I've extracted the CA's public cert from the keycard, placed it as a (verified format) `.pem` file under `/etc/pam_pkcs11/cacerts/`. The full path being `/etc/pam_pkcs11/cacerts/X_CA_Class_B_03.pem`.

I've also created the sym-link needed in this folder both manually but lately via the tool `pkcs11_make_hash_link` which produces a `X5f12asd.0` symlink to my `X_CA_Class_B_03.pem` file.

All this appears fine, so now to the configuration.

### /etc/pam_pkcs11/pam_pkcs11.conf

```
pam_pkcs11 {
    nullok = true;
    debug = ture;

    use_first_pass = false;

    use_athok = false;

    use_pkcs11_module = externalModule;

    pkcs11_module externalModule {
        module = /opt/extlib/libp11.so;
        description = "My SmartCard lib";

        slot = 2;

        ca_dir = /etc/pam_pkcs11/cacerts;
        crl_dir = /etc/pam_pkcs11/crls;

        cert_policy = ca, crl_off;
        crl_policy = none; # Just for the sake of it
    }

    user_mappers = ldap;

    mapper ldap {
        debug = true;
        module = "/usr/lib64/pam_pkcs11/ldap_mapper.so";

        ldaphost = "10.0.0.3";

        ldapport = ;

        URI = "";

        scope = 2;
        binddn = "dn=admin,dc=server,dc=world";
        paswd = "superSecretPasswort_nonotreally";

        base = "dc=server,dc=world";

        attribute = "userCertificate";
        filter = "(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=%s))"

        ssl = off
    }
}
```

### /etc/pam.d/sudo

```
auth    required    pam_pkcs11.so debug
```

I've set up a user matching the username against the certificates **Subject** `x5000UniqueID` and `SerialNumber` fields.
I use this in combination with the correct pin and sudo to test the certificate setup:

```
su testclient
sudo ls
```

This generates the following output:

```
DEBUG:pam_config.c:248: Using config file /etc/pam_pkcs11/pam_pkcs11.conf
DEBUG:pam_config.c:203: Invalid CRL policy: crl_off 
DEBUG:pkcs11_lib.c:187: Initializing NSS ...
DEBUG:pkcs11_lib.c:197: Initializing NSS ... database=/etc/pam_pkcs11/nssdb
DEBUG:pkcs11_lib.c:215: ... NSS Complete
DEBUG:pam_pkcs11.c:308: username = [testclient]
DEBUG:pam_pkcs11.c:319: loading pkcs #11 module...
DEBUG:pkcs11_lib.c:227: Looking up module in list
DEBUG:pkcs11_lib.c:239: modList = 0x12412e0 next = 0x0

DEBUG:pkcs11_lib.c:231: dllName= <null>

DEBUG:pkcs11_lib.c:277: loading Module explictly, moduleSpec=<library="/opt/extlib/libp11.so" name="SmartCard"> module=/opt/extlib/libp11.so
DEBUG:pkcs11_lib.c:291: load module complete
DEBUG:pam_pkcs11.c:334: initialising pkcs #11 module...
Smart card found.
Welcome Smart Card!
Smart card PIN: ##########
DEBUG:pkcs11_lib.c:760: cert 0: found (Smart Card: aut + enc), "E=testing01@example.com,OID.1.3.3.11=#14981257125874433,serialNumber=testclient,CN=Company AB testclient /testclient,givenName=Company AB,SN=testclient,O=Corp,C=COM"
DEBUG:mapper_mgr.c:172: Retrieveing mapper module list
DEBUG:mapper_mgr.c:95: Loading dynamic module for mapper 'ldap'
DEBUG:ldap_mapper.c:1164: test ssltls = off
DEBUG:ldap_mapper.c:1166: LDAP mapper started.
DEBUG:ldap_mapper.c:1167: debug         = 1
DEBUG:ldap_mapper.c:1168: ignorecase    = 0
DEBUG:ldap_mapper.c:1169: ldaphost      = 10.0.0.3
DEBUG:ldap_mapper.c:1170: ldapport      = 0
DEBUG:ldap_mapper.c:1171: ldapURI       =
DEBUG:ldap_mapper.c:1172: scope         = 2
DEBUG:ldap_mapper.c:1173: binddn        = dn=admin,dc=server,dc=world
DEBUG:ldap_mapper.c:1174: passwd        = superSecretPasswort_nonotreally
DEBUG:ldap_mapper.c:1175: base          = dc=server,dc=world
DEBUG:ldap_mapper.c:1176: attribute     = userCertificate
DEBUG:ldap_mapper.c:1177: uid_attribute = (null)
DEBUG:ldap_mapper.c:1181: filter        = (&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=%s))
DEBUG:ldap_mapper.c:1182: searchtimeout = 20
DEBUG:ldap_mapper.c:1183: ssl_on        = 0
DEBUG:ldap_mapper.c:1185: tls_randfile  =
DEBUG:ldap_mapper.c:1186: tls_cacertfile=
DEBUG:ldap_mapper.c:1187: tls_cacertdir =
DEBUG:ldap_mapper.c:1188: tls_checkpeer = -1
DEBUG:ldap_mapper.c:1189: tls_ciphers   =
DEBUG:ldap_mapper.c:1190: tls_cert      =
DEBUG:ldap_mapper.c:1191: tls_key       =
DEBUG:mapper_mgr.c:196: Inserting mapper [ldap] into list
DEBUG:pam_pkcs11.c:551: verifying the certificate #1
verifying certificate
DEBUG:cert_vfy.c:34: Verifying Cert: Smart Card: aut + enc (E=testing01@example.com,OID.1.3.3.11=#14981257125874433,serialNumber=testclient,CN=Company AB testclient /testclient,givenName=Company AB,SN=testclient,O=Corp,C=COM)
DEBUG:cert_vfy.c:38: Couldn't verify Cert: Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user.
ERROR:pam_pkcs11.c:585: verify_certificate() failed:
ERROR:pam_pkcs11.c:646: no valid certificate which meets all requirements found
Error 2336: No matching certificate found
DEBUG:mapper_mgr.c:213: unloading mapper module list
DEBUG:mapper_mgr.c:137: calling mapper_module_end() ldap
DEBUG:mapper_mgr.c:145: unloading module ldap
```

Now this is a lot of information, what it boils down to is basically this (from my understanding):

```
DEBUG:cert_vfy.c:38: Couldn't verify Cert: Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user.
```

Shouldn't this be solved by exporting the CA from the SmartCard, placing it in `/etc/pam_pkcs11/cacerts/` and creating the correct symlink?

*(on a small note, it does actually connect to my LDAP and pre-ask it some stuff.. Does this have anything to do with it? Do pam_pkcs11 check the CA in LDAP or?)*

Where am I going wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add certificate via `certutil` to database located in your case at `/etc/pam_pkcs11/nssdb` as well as making hashes at `/etc/pam_pkcs11/cacerts`

`certutil -A -n nick_of_my_CA -t "TC,C,T" -d /etc/pam_pkcs11/nssdb -i my_ca.crt`

Comment: I know it's a year after, but I came across this issue today :)

Comment: Never thought this would be answered, I'll verify as soon as possible and mark this as solved! :) Awesome job answering this in case anyone else comes along!